# How to write mock for dynamodbattribute.unmarshal function

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

Let us say I have a function which updates the item in DDB and unmarshals the object like below.

```
func update(ddbClient) {
    updatedItem, err := ddbClient.updateItem(...)
    obj := new(MyCustomObj)
    err := dynamodbattribute.UnMarshalMap(updatedItem.Attributes, &obj)
    if err != nil {
     fmt.println("Error while unmarshalling")
   }
}
```

Now I need to write a mock test so that unmarshalMap throws error and I can write a test for that.

Please note that, I already have a mock for UpdateItem, but it cannot throw illegal json as it might break in the place I don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own interface structure to parse dynamo objects an then mock it.

```
type ItemParser interface {
   UnmarshalMap(map[string]interface{}, interface{}) error
}

type DynamoParser struct{}
(dynamo DynamoParser) func UnmarshalMap(attrs map[string]interface{},obj interface{}) error {
   return dynamodbattribute.UnMarshalMap(attr,obj)
}

type ErrorParser struct{
  Err error
}

(errParser ErrorParser ) func UnmarshalMap(map[string]interface{}, interface{}) error {
   return errParser.Err
}

type MyDatabase struct {
  itemParser ItemParser
}

(db MyDatabase) func update(ddbClient) {
    updatedItem, err := ddbClient.updateItem(...)
    obj := new(MyCustomObj)
    err := db.itemParser.UnMarshalMap(updatedItem.Attributes, &obj)
    if err != nil {
     fmt.println("Error while unmarshalling")
   }

}
```

Although seems that you are trying to exercise all logic paths. Not quite sure why you need to do that but if you're following code coverage I do not recommend going 100%